# Copying dynamic table

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use VBA to copy a dynamic range from sheet "Ingredients, recipe database" to sheet "Full list with duplicates - 0's" but I've been struggling to get it working.

[image]

Comment: Please take a moment to familiarize yourself with how this site works. Learn [ask], then edit your question before it gets closed.

Comment: You must clearly define what will you achieve with your question, for example what do you mean with copy dynamically